# Overlaid text on a .pdf translation

Tags: pdf, translation, google-translate, poppler

When you use Google Translate to translate a PDF document made searchable by an OCR tool from a PDF image, the translated text that is generated is well positioned but overwritten on the original images and, as such, unreadable. Many discussions on the [Google Translate forum](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/204048194) were opened and are now closed without any solution (like using Adobe PDF Reader which does not work etc).

A first solution consists in using

```
$ pdftotext text_output_from_google_translate.pdf
```

and the result is a text file `text_output_from_google_translate.txt` .

`pdftotext` comes from the [poppler suite](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) but, and here is my question:
"How can I approximately preserve the positions and pages of translated text that was positioned on the pdf of Google Translate but overlaid?"